# How to change Switch/toggle button state from another activity

Tags: java, android

Ive done something like this. Im receiving 'true' value from 2nd activity and when i receive that it should change my switch button state to OFF. Becouse we need to put manually switch to ON possition. I think it should work but it didnt

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        //ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        final Switch sswitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
        sswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean val) {
                val = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("toggleBtn", false);
                if(val)
                 {
                    sswitch.setChecked(false);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

In 2nd activity as i said im sending that value to the first one

```
 public void backtomain(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AalarmActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", true);
        finish();

    }
```

Comment: Saying right `isChecked ` is not static method in `ToggleButton ` so need to use `ToggleButton` object to access it. Why not using `((ToggleButton)view).isChecked()` instead of `ToggleButton.isChecked()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as you are asking if `isChecked` on your first if, with  :

```
((ToggleButton)view).isChecked();
```

Then in your `Intent` put this :

```
intent.putExtras("toggleBtn", ((ToggleButton)view).isChecked());
```

### EDIT

Acording on your code it will only make the `Intent` when the `ToggleButton` is true, isnt' it? Then if it enters on the `if` it means that the `ToggleButton` is enabled, so instead of pass `((ToggleButton)view).isChecked()` on your `putExtras` you can pass `true` instead, then make an `else` and putting it to `false`

### EDIT 2

I think you forgot the `startActivity()` on :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AalarmActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Error:(66, 19) error: no suitable method found for putExtras(String,boolean)
method Intent.putExtras(Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Intent.putExtras(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

I was trying to do like this before but i stopped when i saw this message :(

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ITS WORKING !!

Comment: Glad to help you @kociolekpanoramixa :)